# python 3 new to classes

Tags: class, function, python-3.x

I'm .self taught in python and need some help with a really simple class I'm trying to write. I would like to use everything outside of the InitLog class in various modules WITHOUT needing to declare a new class variable everytime i use it (eg i dont want to declare betty = Initlog in every (numerous) module i wish to use the class ... is there a way i can do this? Thanks in advance

```
import os
import sys
import pdb
import fileinput
import Tools


class InitLog:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def Update(self):
        self.sound = sound
        self.engine = engine

    def save(self):

        self.summery = 'sound: ' + self.sound + '\n'
        self.summery += 'engine: ' + self.engine + '\n'


        #lock for use within threads
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False
        while Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress == True: pass
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = True

        try: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        except: pass

        path = os.getcwd()
        if not os.path.exists(self.dest): os.makedirs(self.dest)
        if os.path.isfile(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log') == True: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        with open (path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
            a_file.write(self.summery)
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False



InitLog.Update.sound = 'on'
InitLog.Update.engine = 'google.txt'
InitLog.save()
```

error: `TypeError: save() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)`

**EDIT:**

I have shorted the above example to be less redundant.

Here is the working code i was previously using (before attepting my original request to use InitLog without declaring a new class variable)

```
import os
import sys
import pdb
import fileinput
import Tools


class InitLog:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def setLaws(self):
        self.sound = 'off'
        self.engine = 'google.txt'


    def Update(self):
        while Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress == True: pass
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = True
        try: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        except: pass

        summery = 'sound: ' + self.sound + '\n'
        summery += 'engine: ' + self.engine + '\n'


        path = os.getcwd()
        if not os.path.exists(self.dest): os.makedirs(self.dest)
        if os.path.isfile(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log') == True: os.remove(path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log')
        with open (path + '/' + self.dest + '/init.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
            a_file.write(summery)
        Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False

Tools.Locked.State.LogAddress = False
log = InitLog()
log.setLaws()
log.sound = 'on'
log.Update()
```

I would like to not need to say `log = InitLog()` for every module i need to use this class

Comment: This use of classes is pretty much all wrong. I suggest you first go back and read about classes, instanatiation, and method calling.

Comment: [`@classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) would help on `save()` and `Update()` above, but as Keith said you have other problems with that code

Comment: hey Mike, I've included my original working code (before deciding i wanted to not declare InitLog on every module)

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly using classes.

The following code:

```
InitLog.Update.sound = 'on'
InitLog.Update.engine = 'google.txt'
InitLog.Update.countryspec = '.com'
InitLog.Update.limit = '10'
....
```

is accessing the method object of Update of the class InitLog, and adding attributes to it on the fly. This attributes are being attached to the function object not the class or an object of that class.

`error: TypeError: save() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)` save is a method it requires a parameter self which is set implicitly when an instance of an InitLog object calls it.

If you want a single instance through your code, then you can follow the singleton design pattern.

first I recommend you go through http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Maybe you are tying to achieve something like this:

```
class InitLog:
    sound = None
    engine = None
    summary = ""
    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        cls.summary = 'sound: ' + cls.sound + '\n'
        cls.summary += 'engine: ' + cls.engine + '\n'

InitLog.sound = 'On'
InitLog.engine = 'google.txt'
InitLog.save()
print InitLog.summary
```

Heres a different design which may be more reusable later on.

```
class InitLog:
    custom_instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.sound = None
        self.engine = None
        self.summary = ''
    @property
    def sound(self):
        return self.sound
    @sound.setter
    def set_sound(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound
    @property
    def engine(self):
        return self.engine
    @engine.setter
    def set_engine(self, engine):
        self.engine = engine
    @property
    def summary(self):
        return self.summary
    @summary.setter
    def set_summary(self, summary):
        self.summary = summary
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        if 'sound' in kwargs:
            self.sound = kwargs['sound']
        if 'engine' in kwargs:
            self.engine = kwargs['engine']
    def save(self):
        self.summary = 'sound: ' + self.sound + '\n'
        self.summary += 'engine: ' + self.engine + '\n'
    @classmethod
    def get_custom_instance(cls):
        if not cls.custom_instance:
            cls.custom_instance = InitLoc()
            cls.custom_instance.engine = 'google.txt'
            cls.custom_instance.sound = 'on'
        return cls.custom_instance

obj = InitLog.get_custom_instance()
obj.save()
print obj.summary  #ouput => 'sound: on\nengine: google.txt\n'
print obj.update(sound = 'Off')
obj.save()
print obj.summary  #output =>'sound: Off\nengine: google.txt\n'
```

There are many ways of designing python classes or classes in general for that matter, this are just 2, please go through the guide and find the best design that suits your needs.

Comment: You need to read his question carefully... "I would like to use everything outside of the InitLog class in various modules WITHOUT needing to declare a new class variable everytime i use it"

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've included my original working code (before deciding i wanted to not declare InitLog on every module). As you can see it contains the slimier declaration of InitLog to what you have made